# how do I auto authenticate google javascript api ? REST api

Tags: javascript, php, google-api

I am using php. and want to use some javascript api function in my application. so can any one know that how can I auto authenticate this process:

```
<!--Add a button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
<button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var clientId = '837050751313';

  var apiKey = 'AIzaSyAdjHPT5Pb7Nu56WJ_nlrMGOAgUAtKjiPM';

  var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Step 2: Reference the API key
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  }

  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
  }

  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      makeApiCall();
    } else {
      authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
    }
  }

  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    // Step 3: get authorization to use private data
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
  }

  // Load the API and make an API call.  Display the results on the screen.
  function makeApiCall() {
    // Step 4: Load the Google+ API
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1').then(function() {
      // Step 5: Assemble the API request
      var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        'userId': 'me'
      });
      // Step 6: Execute the API request
      request.then(function(resp) {
        var heading = document.createElement('h4');
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = resp.result.image.url;
        heading.appendChild(image);
        heading.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.result.displayName));

        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(heading);
      }, function(reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    });
  }
</script>
// Step 1: Load JavaScript client library
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

I have .json and also .p12 file for authenticate but I only want to direct access to api function instead of redirecting to google for permission access.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Google+ API or other API that accesses user-specific data (e.g. Gmail, Calendar), you need to either use an OAuth client and ask the user for permission to access their data (i.e. the "redirect to google for permission access"), or use a service account.

A service account is a robot account that is used in place of a real user. If you decide to use a service account, you'll need to use the JSON or P12 key as you mentioned. Using a service account from JavaScript code requires a lot of work and is generally insecure since you would be making your service account key accessible to everyone. If you're going to use a service account, you should call the API from the server [using a Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests).

Comment: I have already used php client api. but I want to hide spreadsheet column, and thai is not possible with php client api. and yes I want to access service of google. and hide column of sheet is possible by javascript api.